# How to create a ssl for magento 2.4 localhost

Tags: server-setup, elasticsearch, magento2.4

I want to install magento 2.4 in localhost, but it is asking for elastic search and ssl, now how to create a ssl for local server.

Answer (score 0):

I use `mkcert` for creating local SSL certificates for development.

https://github.com/FiloSottile/mkcert